Linphone and Raspberry Pi Python script call on button press problems with setting PATH
I have installed linphone with the following guide:
https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/
I have fiew to none experience with python.
I found a script that reacts on a button press and this seems to work, but the command I want to make is not working.
My Script:
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as gpio
from subprocess import call
import time
import subprocess
import os


gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(5, gpio.IN, pull_up_down = gpio.PUD_UP)
os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/pi/linphone-sdk/build-raspberry/linphone-sdk/desktop/bin'

subprocess.Popen(["sudo -u pi linphonecsh init -a -C -c /home/pi/.linphonerc -d 6 -l /tmp/log.txt"])

def doorbell(channel):


    subprocess.Popen(["linphonecsh dial **9"])
    
gpio.add_event_detect(5, gpio.FALLING, callback=doorbell, bouncetime=300)

while 1:
    time.sleep(360)

I get this error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo -u pi linphonecsh init -a -C -c /home/pi/.linphonerc -d 6 -l /tmp/log.txt'

This seems to be the case because the PATH variable is not set right.
I also tried to set the PATH in the "/etc/rc.local" like in the guide is set. Also I tried to set it in /etc/crontab.
How do I set the Path right?

Since you are using python to make your script, why not build the linphone SDK's python wrapper?
https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk#python-wrapper-wheel-packaging
This way you can more easily control your calls etc...
Cheers,

I tried to install the python wrapper from the documentary on their official website. But I always get this error:
WARNING: Requirement 'linphone-3.10.2_834_gb95a9b8-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: linphone-3.10.2_834_gb95a9b8-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

3.10 is a very old release of deprecated python wrapper (it's no longer available). I meant the new python wrapper (5.4.0-alpha version) but you have to build it yourself for now as there is no pre-built wheel yet.
